# Can anyone correct this syntax in laravel View?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel

Can anyone correct this syntax in laravel View?
I want to display my Ajax Data in View and I want to Add Charts in View... not THE CONTROLLER...... 
I know the guidelines of `ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts;`

```
{{ Charts::multi(array('bar', 'material')) }}
{{ Charts::title("Weather Charts") }}
{{ Charts::dimensions(array(0, 400)) }}
{{ Charts::template("material") }}
{{ Charts::dataset(array('Element 1', array(5,20,100))) }}
{{ Charts::dataset(array('Element 1', array(5,20,100))) }}
{{ Charts::dataset(array('Element 1', array(5,20,100))) }}
{{ Charts::labels(array('One', 'Two', 'Three')) }}
{{ $chart->render() }}
```

this is my code for View.... and please correct anyone i guess this is Wrong.....

and if someone have code ready please share a link

Comment: Which package did you use for creating charts?

Comment: ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts;

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the ConsoleTV's Charts the syntax should be like this:

**Controller & View usage:**

Put the following in your controller and return the variable to your view.

```
$chart = Charts::multi(array('bar', 'material'))
    ->title("Weather Charts")
    ->dimensions(0, 400)
    ->template("material")
    ->dataset(array('Element 1', array(5,20,100)))
    ->dataset(array('Element 2', array(5,20,100)))
    ->dataset(array('Element 3', array(5,20,100)))
    ->labels(array('One', 'Two', 'Three'));
```

In your view you can now use

```
{{ $chart->render() }}
```

**View only usage through blade**

Using the code in blade itself (without the use of a controller):

```
{{ Charts::multi(array('bar', 'material'))->title("Weather Charts")->dimensions(0, 400)->template("material")->dataset(array('Element 1', array(5,20,100)))->dataset(array('Element 2', array(5,20,100)))->dataset(array('Element 3', array(5,20,100)))->labels(array('One', 'Two', 'Three'))->render() }}
```

Just string it all together as the Chart class returns itself through its methods you can string methods.

There may be errors in the arguments for certain tags, but you should have no issues in solving those.

Comment: i want to bind Ajax data..... and that can retrieve in View only.... This code will not work....

Comment: You didn't state that you wanted to add data through the use of ajax calls.Please update your question with the relevant data to be added through ajax.

Comment: yeah great...wait for a Min

Comment: I've altered my answer to answer your comment for blade only.

Comment: `Missing argument 2 for ConsoleTVs\Charts\Builder\Chart::dimensions(),`

this is Error Showing

Comment: @RushabhShah the code was translated from your example, i've altered the dimensions as it's supposed to have 2 arguments instead of an array.

Comment: SORRY TO SAY
BUT code was Working Properly in Controller....

I want that code in View INSTEAD OF CONTROLLER.....

Comment: Calm down please, I'm trying to help you.

Comment: yeah... sorry for inconvenience

Comment: can you write any Mail ID where can we talk?

because this comment  box has limits to show my Emotions
@Niek van der Maaden